# Kernel error when installing Linux Mint

Tags: linux, virtualbox, 64-bit, cinnamon

I'm getting this error:

```
"This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU"
```

I have enabled:

- Virtualization in BIOS
- VT-x
- Nested Paging
- IO-APIC

but I still get this problem while installing 64 bit Linux Mint Cinnamon over my 64 bit Windows 8.

My processor is an AMD A4-4300m.

Comment: Did you check to make sure all the relevant BIOS settings are enabled?

Comment: i think so , its in virtual box , so i didnt change the secure boot etc options in BIOS.

Comment: Sometimes there are other extensions than VT-x, like I/O virtualization (VT-d). If you have any of those, try disabling them (but leave VT-x enabled). Sometimes they cause problems. If they're already disabled, try enabling them.

Answer (score 0):

In the VirtualBox settings for the virtual machine, on the general -> basic tab, make sure the "version" for the "linux" type is set to 64-bit and not 32-bit.